# JQuery .width won't work within my if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

My problem is that for some reason my .width wont work and I can't figure out why. JQuery is referenced correctly in the html file and the id is correctly inserted. (I think :/ sorry if this is just a rookie mistake as i believe it is. however i have looked around for a solution and as of yet have found one.) here is my JavaScript.

```
window.onload;
function detectmob() {
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
    return true;
  }
 else {
    return false;
  }
}
if(detectmob()){
  window.alert('success');
  $('#content').width("100%");
} else {
  window.alert('fail');
}
```

and here is my html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Autofresh</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="styles/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="styles/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="header">
        //image goes here
        <div id="navbar">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="video"></div>
      <div id="registration">

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated as I am still in the process of learning JavaScript and JQuery and am by no means an expert, quite the opposite. Thank you in advance for any help that is given.

Comment: Just use `return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent);` in function.

Comment: `window.onload;` ?

Comment: I bet your console says `$ is undefined`.

Comment: Any error message in the console? What happens instead of the expected result? You see the alert?

Comment: You are referencing the element before it is on the page. It is like trying to eat a pizza before it is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I made some minor changes the first is `navigator.userAgent.match(/Mozilla/i)` so you can test it from a browser, you might want to remove that later on. The second is I moved the JQuery reference into the body, I also wrapped the JavaScript in a document.ready. Hope that helps

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(detectmob()){
      console.log("success");
      $('#content').width("100%");
    } else {
      console.log("navigator.userAgent");
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/63nm4cxs/

> $ is undefined.

This was your main issue, JQuery wasn't referenced!

Comment: Thank you for the help i was stuck on this for a while rookie error on my behalf :p @J Newton

Comment: @James Anderson Glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

```
    //Include jquery before this code.
function detectmob() {
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
    return true;
  }
 else {
    return false;
  }
}
// on window load    
$(window).load(function() {
     if(detectmob()){
      window.alert('success');
$('#content').css('width',"100%");
//$('#content').width("100%");
    } else {
      window.alert('fail');
    }
    });
```

Comment: Explanation would be nice.

Comment: We are going to detect the device in window load function and then apply the width. What you were doing was applying the width before the div is rendered.

Comment: no need for .css('width'). .width('100%) will work just fine.

Comment: Yes I agree but its just to make sure width is applied.